# RStudio wants to download/install the wrong package version

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to install the package "sjlabelled":

```
> install.packages("sjlabelled")
Installing package into ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjlabelled_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjlabelled_1.0.1.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sjlabelled_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘sjlabelled’ failed
```

but this fails due to the error above. On https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ you can see that there are only newer versions of this package available (instead of 1.0.1 there is 1.0.2/1.0.3). 
How can I teach my RStudio to download the correct version?

**edit:** Besides the accepted answer of Lyngbakr there is also a handy option to do it directly in the RStudio GUI by Tools/Install Packages/ and choose in "Install from/ Package Archive File (.tar.gz)". Then, below, in Package archive you can select your downloaded file. Then all you need is to hit "install".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the latest (development) version via `devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjlabelled")`

Comment: Thanks! But where do I put this line in?

Comment: Here is the full reference you need to install dev tools package and rtools.exe [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/README.html) you can simply enter the above line in Rstudio console and hit enter

Comment: Ah, ok. Is it advisable to install the devtools package? I have critical stuff and further software settings on my PC so I'm a bit concerned.

Comment: @Ben I think it's probably personal preference. I like to have the latest and don't mind the possibility of bugs. After all, I can always go back to the stable release if it is too buggy. If you use this command to install the development version, you just load the library as per usual. You'll also need the `devtools` library.

Comment: @Ben  FYI you can use [`install_version`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.3/topics/install_version) to specify particular versions of a package, but I think that is more for installing old versions.

Answer (score 0):

Download the package.
Try:

```
 install.packages("sjlabelled_1.0.3.zip",lib="/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4",repos=NULL)
```

As specified in GitHub page https://github.com/strengejacke/sjlabelled :

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjlabelled")
```

Here is the full reference you need to install dev tools package and rtools.exe https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/README.html you can simply enter the above line in Rstudio console and hit enter

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it does not work. Thought the data format was wrong (tar.gz instead of .zip) but it didn't affect anything: Warning: invalid package ‘sjlabelled_1.0.3.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sjlabelled_1.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status